# EXCEL VLOOKUP multiple outcomes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, data-analysis

How can I retrieve multiple values using vlookup and then transform all those values into columns next to each other?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the filter function combined with transpose to accomplish what you want.

Here's [a sample on google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ViDaK6xNFt2CMQ2Y9lBVn1i7LRU-onzA3o2hKCkJHXk/edit?usp=sharing), but it would also work on Excel provided you have Spill-Range functionality...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use Office 365 you can use the solution provided by pgSystemTester:

`=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B4:B9,A4:A9=C2))`

Where `C2` contains the search value,
`A4:A9` contains the values to match the search value,
`B4:B9` contains the result values.

If an Excel version prior to O365 is used, this could be done by:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$4:$A$9)/($A$4:$A$9=$C$2),COLUMN(A:A))),"")`
This indexes column B with the row numbers where a match is found on the search value `C2` in `A4:A9`. The smallest row number matching is indexed and when copied to the right the 2nd smallest, etc.

Note 1: the `INDEX` part of the function uses whole column reference.

Note 2: Only in the `COLUMN` part of the function the `$` is omitted in the range reference. This will result in changing the range reference to the right when copied to the right.